# Computing difficult Fourier series numerically - software recommendation

Tags: math-software

I need to compute some pretty complex Fourier series of function like this one:

$$
f(t) = \quad 
\begin{cases}
1+e^{-t}, & t\in [0;1)\\
2, & t \in [1;3)
\end{cases}
$$

Rewritten to "one-line form:

$$
heaviside(x) * heaviside(1-x) * (1 + exp(-x)) + heaviside(x-1) * heaviside(3-x)
$$

With period T=3.

---

When I tried to compute it by WolframAlpha, I got just "Computing time exceeded" error - [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier%20series%20of%20%28heaviside%28x%29%20*%20heaviside%281-x%29%20*%20%281%20%2B%20exp%28-x%29%29%20%2B%20heaviside%28x-1%29%20*%20heaviside%283-x%29%20*%20%282%29,x,n%29).

Do you have any idea, how could I compute this series? As far as I know, MatLab/Octave doesn't have any function for this...

Comment: This looks simple enough that you should be able to do the necessary integrals symbolically -- but if you want a Fouries _series_, then the function ought to be periodic. With which period?

Comment: @HenningMakholm The period is T=3. Symbolically? You mean in e.g. MatLab? Maybe I should be, but, unfortunately, I'm not very experienced in this (neither with MatLab nor Fourier Transform)... I've added info about the period into the question.

Comment: In this particular case you should actually be able to do them by hand. The only tricky thing is the exponential piece but that can be done using integration by parts.

Comment: No, I mean with pencil and paper. You should get something like $$ c_n = \frac13 \int_0^1(1+\exp(-t))\exp(-i\frac{2\pi}{3}nt)\,dt + \frac13 \int_1^3 2\exp(-i\frac{2\pi}{3}nt)\,dt $$ where all three terms are straightforward to find an antiderivative for by hand.

Comment: @Ian: Even the exponential piece is simple, by $e^{at}e^{bt}=e^{(a+b)t}$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm In complex exponential form it is indeed easy, it's just a bit trickier in trigonometric form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Too long for a comment]

Here’s what Mathematica finds, with the function period scaled to $2\pi$.

```
f[t_]=Piecewise[{
  {1+E^(-(3/(2\[Pi]))Mod[t,2\[Pi]]),0<=Mod[t,2\[Pi]]<2/3 \[Pi]},
  {2,2/3 \[Pi]<=Mod[t,2\[Pi]]<2\[Pi]}
}]
s[t_]=FourierSeries[f[t],t,10]
Plot[{f[t],s[t]},{t,0,2\[Pi]}]
```

$2-\frac{1}{3 e}-\frac{i (-1+e) e^{3 i t-1}}{3 (-i+2 \pi )}+\frac{i (-1+e) e^{-3 i t-1}}{3 (i+2 \pi )}-\frac{i (-1+e) e^{6 i t-1}}{3 (-i+4 \pi )}+\frac{i (-1+e) e^{-6 i t-1}}{3 (i+4 \pi )}-\frac{i (-1+e) e^{9 i t-1}}{3 (-i+6 \pi )}+\frac{i (-1+e) e^{-9 i t-1}}{3 (i+6 \pi )}+\frac{e^{-2 i t} \left(9 e+3 i \sqrt{3} e+4 i \pi -4 \sqrt{3} \pi -4 i e \pi +4 \sqrt{3} e \pi \right)}{24 i e \pi +32 e \pi ^2}+\frac{e^{10 i t-1} \left(20 \pi  \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right)+e \left(-20 \pi  \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right)+3 \sqrt{3} i+9\right)\right)}{40 \pi  (-3 i+20 \pi )}+\frac{e^{7 i t-1} \left(14 \pi  \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right)+e \left(-14 \pi  \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right)+3 \sqrt{3} i+9\right)\right)}{28 \pi  (-3 i+14 \pi )}+\frac{e^{4 i t-1} \left(8 \pi  \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right)+e \left(-8 \pi  \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right)+3 \sqrt{3} i+9\right)\right)}{16 \pi  (-3 i+8 \pi )}+\frac{e^{i t-1} \left(e \left(-2 \pi  \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right)+3 \sqrt{3} i+9\right)-4 (-1)^{5/6} \pi \right)}{4 \pi  (-3 i+2 \pi )}+\frac{e^{-5 i t-1} \left(e \left(10 \pi  \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right)+3 \sqrt{3} i+9\right)-10 \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \pi \right)}{20 \pi  (3 i+10 \pi )}+\frac{e^{-8 i t-1} \left(e \left(16 \pi  \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right)+3 \sqrt{3} i+9\right)-16 \left(-i+\sqrt{3}\right) \pi \right)}{32 \pi  (3 i+16 \pi )}+\frac{e^{-i t-1} \left(4 \sqrt[6]{-1} \pi -e \left(2 \pi  \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right)+3 \sqrt{3} i-9\right)\right)}{4 \pi  (3 i+2 \pi )}+\frac{e^{2 i t-1} \left(e \left(4 \pi  \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right)-3 i \sqrt{3}+9\right)-4 \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \pi \right)}{8 \pi  (-3 i+4 \pi )}+\frac{e^{-4 i t-1} \left(8 \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \pi -e \left(8 \pi  \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right)+3 \sqrt{3} i-9\right)\right)}{16 \pi  (3 i+8 \pi )}+\frac{e^{5 i t-1} \left(e \left(10 \pi  \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right)-3 i \sqrt{3}+9\right)-10 \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \pi \right)}{20 \pi  (-3 i+10 \pi )}+\frac{e^{-7 i t-1} \left(14 \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \pi -e \left(14 \pi  \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right)+3 \sqrt{3} i-9\right)\right)}{28 \pi  (3 i+14 \pi )}+\frac{e^{8 i t-1} \left(e \left(16 \pi  \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right)-3 i \sqrt{3}+9\right)-16 \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \pi \right)}{32 \pi  (-3 i+16 \pi )}+\frac{e^{-10 i t-1} \left(20 \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right) \pi -e \left(20 \pi  \left(i+\sqrt{3}\right)+3 \sqrt{3} i-9\right)\right)}{40 \pi  (3 i+20 \pi )}$

[image]